# Java generic : Restricting a class to specific implementations.

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Config<T> implements Proxy<T> {
    public abstract T parse();
    public T get() {....}
}

public class IntegerConfig<Integer> extends Config<Integer> {
    public Integer parse() {...}
}

public class LongConfig<Long> extends Config<Long> {
    public Long parse() {...}
}

public class IntegerListConfig<List<Integer>> extends Config<List<Integer>> {
    public List<Integer> parse() {....}
}
```

And so on...

I'd like to introduce a new class:

```
public class ConfigMutation<T> implements Proxy<T> {
    public ConfigMutation(....) {
        //// create a concrete implementation of Config<T> according to actual parameterized type
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'd like to avoid repeating the entire class hierarchy of Config, and support in ConfigMutation all types that have parameterized implementations in Config class hierarchy.

Couldn't find a way to do it. `(Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0]` obviously returns T, and not the actual type.

Also, once this problem is solved, I'd be happy if someone could suggest some factory pattern with generic types, so when I'm instantiating a Config derived class inside ConfigMutation, I wouldn't have to do it with a huge if...else block on actual type.

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: `public class ConfigMutation<T extends Config<T>> implements Proxy<T>` ?

Comment: Thanks!!!
 I'm disappointed at myself :-)

Comment: No need to be disappointed. Generics are confusing at times. See my answer.

Comment: `IntegerListConfig<List<Integer>> extends Config<List<Integer>>` this will bite you in the butt. You can override the issues that arise if you create a class that extends `ArrayList<Integer>` though and use it as a concrete class... or if you follow suit and steal `$Gson$Types`'s reimplementation of the Oracle internal reflection stuff.

Comment: On a sidenote, I don't really understand what you're actually trying to do in a `ConfigMutation`.

Comment: I know it will bite me, but I have no choice because I'm working against an exiting API.

Comment: As for what I'm trying to do - the Config<T> is used to get and cache configuration from a DB. It gets the key of the config to load. But now we'd like to support multiple configurations for the "same" key, but to be able to alter it per service, so I want to provide the service name and the key, and get the config for that service (or the default config of the key if it is not overridden in the service level)

Comment: @LiorChaga I have edited my answer. What EpicPandaForce said and what I already pointed out in my answer is that the `List<Integer>` in the`IntegerListConfig<List<Integer>>` will not compile because `List` used in this context will be considered as a type parameter. It's similar to saying `T<Integer>` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually it does compile...

Comment: @LiorChaga The statement `class IntegerListConfig<List<Integer>> extends Config<List<Integer>> {
    public List<Integer> parse() {return null;}
}` does not compile for me on JDK 1.8. Can you confirm if this is actually working for you in another version of the JDK? I get two errors. 1. misplaced constructs and 2. The type List is not generic. (And yes, I am importing java.util.List)

Comment: Using JDK 1.6. But I see that the class is actually declared as `class IntegerListConfig extends Config<List<Integer>>`

Comment: @LiorChaga So it doesn't compile if we use the code in your quesiton right? Just making sure I am not assuming that it doesn't compile.

Comment: No it doesn't. I mistyped the code sample (didn't copy from the real code, because I wanted to simplify the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ConfigMutation` class to :

```
public class ConfigMutation<U,T extends Config<U>> implements Proxy<U> {
    public ConfigMutation() {

    }
}
```

You can then use `ConfigMutation` as :

```
ConfigMutation<Integer,IntegerConfig> mutation;
```

You won't be able to do something as follows which is what you want :

```
ConfigMutation<String,IntegerConfig> mutation;
```

That said, there is a change you need to make to your concrete `Config` implementers as well. For example, change `IntegerConfig` to :

```
public class IntegerConfig extends Config<Integer> {
    public Integer parse() {...}
}
```

The `Integer` in `IntegerConfig<Integer>` will be considered as a type parameter and not the `Integer` class which is not what you want. (An IDE should give you a warning for this; *The type parameter Integer is hiding the type Integer*)

Comment: My happiness was too early:
'ConfigMutation<IntegerConfig> mutation = new ConfigMutation<IntegerConfig>' gives me "IntegerConfig is not within its bounds". Doesn't work also when I'm trying ConfigMutation<Config<Integer>>.

Comment: @LiorChaga My bad. Edited.

Comment: Yep, it works now. The problem was indeed the "T extends Config<T>". The proxy should also be "Proxy<U>". Thanks!!

Comment: @LiorChaga I didn't know what `Proxy` was supposed to do. Edited.